# Is there a way to revert back to the command line after opening an application through it?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I want to be able to open an application on the command line, but instead of switching to the application, I want to stay on my terminal emulator. Is there a way of accomplishing this? I am using OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-g` flag of [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html), which avoids bringing the app to the foreground.

```
$ open -g /Applications/TextEdit.app
$
```

`open` will start the app, and then return to the command prompt.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Many thanks.  Who knew manpages could be so useful :)

Comment: @trojanfoe We all `know` they can be useful - it's just remembering to read the things - when we `think` we know what the command does :-)

Comment: As a follow up, would there be a way to do something similar with bash scripts? I have a script that opens a VirtualBox session using vmboxmanager, since opening the VirtualBox app itself does not allow me to go straight into my virtual machine (the app takes me to a virtual machine manager first).

Comment: You'll need to use `&` when invoking any command that doesn't terminate by itself.  The reason you don't need `&` with `open` is that I believe it hands the work over to `launchctl` (and friends) allowing it to terminate while the app continues to run.  In the case of VirtualBox, I'm not sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

After you run the program hit `ctrl+z` and type `bg`. You will return to your terminal CLI.

Whenever you want to go back to your program, just type `fg`.

Answer (score 0):

You can background the job. In the Bash shell, this is done with the `&`. For example:

```
some_script_or_application &
```

Note that some daemons and processes background themselves. For example, on OS X, running  `open some.pdf` will preview the PDF in a GUI while returning the command prompt immediately without needing to do anything special.

See the GNU Bash Manual for more on [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html) for background jobs.

Comment: You still lose input focus if you do that... you will notice your prompt becomes hollow.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's a misfeature of the window manager, and has nothing to do with the shell or with background jobs in general.

Comment: Possibly - but starting the job in the background does not address the OP's requirement which was `to stay in his Terminal emulator`.